# lm() in R, simple example

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

Here is my example.

```
train_df <- data.frame(x =seq(1,8), 
                       y = c(0.0007034055, 0.0022187427, 0.0037911817,
                             0.0036339630, 0.0044425459,0.0038392539, 0.0055802326, 0.0060052847))
lin_fit = lm(y~x, data = train_df )

new_df <- data.frame(x = seq(9,32))
y_hat <- predict(lin_fit, new_data = new_df)
```

I believe at 10 it should produce

```
lin_fit$coefficients[[2]]*10 + lin_fit$coefficients[[1]]

0.007369728
```

while it generates:

```
y_hat[[2]]
0.002143689
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The argument is `newdata`, not `new_data`. Because of the misspelling, `predict` ignored the argument and returned predictions for the original data, not the new data. If you type `y_hat` in the console, you'll see that `predict` returned only eight prediction values.

Comment: @eipi10, thank you so much!